# Find a recurrence relation for the number of ternary strings of length n that contain either two consecutive 0s or two consecutive 1s.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I've been stuck on this one for a little bit now. I've looked at the other similar questions on here, but I don't understand the general process for going about forming a recurrence relation from this. How should I go about looking at this problem?

Comment: Can the strings contain both two consecutive $0$'s and two consecutive $1$'s? Can they contain a run of more than two consecutive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $b_n$ be the number of $n$-digit ternary strings which begin with $0$ and contain neither $00$ nor $11$.  Let $c_n,d_n$ be the same except starting with $1$ or $2$ respectively.  Let
$$t_n=b_n+c_n+d_n$$
be the total number of $n$-digit ternary strings which contain neither $00$ nor $11$.  What you want is
$$a_n=3^n-t_n\ .$$
To find a recurrence for $b_n$ observe that an $n$-digit ternary string which begins with $0$ and contains neither $00$ nor $11$ is

- $0$, followed by an $(n-1)$-digit string which begins with $1$ and contains neither $00$ nor $11$; or
- $0$, followed by an $(n-1)$-digit string which begins with $2$ and contains neither $00$ nor $11$.

Therefore
$$b_n=c_{n-1}+d_{n-1}\ ;$$
similar arguments give
$$c_n=b_{n-1}+d_{n-1}$$
and
$$d_n=b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}+d_{n-1}=t_{n-1}\ .$$
Adding all of these gives
$$t_n=2t_{n-1}+d_{n-1}$$
and so
$$t_n=2t_{n-1}+t_{n-2}\ .$$
Writing in terms of $a_n$, we have
$$3^n-a_n=2(3^{n-1}-a_{n-1})+(3^{n-2}-a_{n-2})$$
which simplifies to
$$a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+2\times3^{n-2}\ .$$

Comment: This way of arriving at a recurrence relation gave a good insight into it

Answer (score 2):

Above answer by Mr.David is excellent, I would like to tell how I developed intuition. We can see that we need either $2$ consecutive $0$'s or $2$ consecutive $1$'s. So we can place $2$ consecutive $0$'s at the end so for the rest of the $n-2$ positions can have any bit out of $3$ hence $3^{n-2}$ possibilities and same for $2$ consecutive 1's so total of $2\times3^{n-2}$.

Now the core thought. We obtained string ending with $00$ or $11$ but string can end with $01$, $02$, $10$, $12$, $20$, $21$ or $22$. So what we can think is that all $n-1$ length string must be ending with the $0$, $1$ or $2$. Now for the $n$'th position we can give $2$ choices for each last bit of $n-1$ string that is if the last bit is $1$ then it has $2$ choices $0$ or $2$ (we can not give $1$ as a choice because it will create string ending with $11$ but we already covered that case). Similarly, $0$ will have $2$ choices for the $n$'th position, either $1$ or $2$, and also $2$ will have $2$ choices (can be any $2$ of the 3 choices). The above corresponds to $2a(n-1)$.

But we know for $2$ all the three i.e. $0$, $1$ and $2$ are valid at the $n$'th position but we counted only $2$ (any $2$ of your choice). Let's say you had counted string ending with $20$ and $22$. The remaining case that strings ends with $21$ can be added by appending $2$ and $1$ to the string of length $n-2$ containing $2$ consecutive $0$'s or $2$ consecutive $1$'s.

So the final intuitive (but right) answer becomes
$$a(n) = 2\times3^{n-2} + 2a(n-1) + a(n-2)\text.$$

Answer (score 0):

This question is included in exercise 8.1-16 of the book "Discrete Mathematics and its Applications 8th edition by Kenneth Rosen". The solution offered by the book is:

> Let $a_n$ be the number of ternary strings that contain either two consecutive 0’s or two consecutive 1’s . To
> construct such a string we could **start with a 2** and follow with a string containing either two consecutive 0’s
> or two consecutive 1’s , and this can be done in $a_{n−1}$ ways.
>
> There are other possibilities, however. For each
> k from 0 to $n −2$ , the string could start with $n −1 −k$ **alternating 0’s and 1’s** , followed by a 2 , and then
> be followed by a string of length k containing either two consecutive 0’s or two consecutive 1’s . The number
> of such strings is $2a_k$ , since there are two ways for the initial part to alternate.
>
> The other possibility is that
> the string has no 2’s at all. Then it must consist $n −k −2$ alternating 0’s and 1’s , followed by **a pair of 0’s
> or 1’s** , followed by any string of length k. There are $2\cdot 3^k$ such strings. Now the sum of these quantities as
> k runs from 0 to n −2 is (since this is a geometric progression) $3^{n−1} −1$ .
>
> Putting this all together, we have
> the following recurrence relation, valid for all $n \ge 2 : a_n = a_{n−1} + 2a_{n−2} + 2a_{n−3} + \cdots+ 2a_{0} + 3^{n−1} −1$. (By
> subtracting this recurrence relation from the same relation with n −1 substituted for n, we can obtain the
> following closed form recurrence relation for this problem: $a_n = 2a_{n−1} + a_{n−2} + 2\cdot 3^{n−2}$.)

The above $2a_k$ only considers "alternating 0’s and 1’s" because the pair of 0's or 1's is considered in the situation related with $3^{n-1}-1$.