# Recurrence for the number of ternary strings of length $n$ that contain either two consecutive $0$s or two consecutive $1$s

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

I attempted this problem and this is what I have so far:

First, I considered the possible "cases".

If the string starts with $00$ or $11$, then the rest can be anything so there are  $2\cdot 3^{n-2}$ such strings.

If the string starts with $2$, then there are $n-1$ strings that contain two consecutive $0$s or $1$s.

If the string starts with $22$, then there are $n-2$ strings that contain two consecutive $0$s or $1$s.

I came up with the recurrence relation:
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+2\cdot 3^{n-1}.$$
However, the solution in my textbook says it is actually
$$a_n=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+2\cdot 3^{n-2}.$$
I can't seem to figure out why $a_{n-1}$ is multiplied by two.

Comment: Read again what you have written: If the string starts with $2$, why there should be only $n-1$ admissible continuations?

Comment: Here *either* stands for $\text{OR}$ or for $\text{XOR}$? (I guess the latter, but I am not that confident in this linguistic nuances).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741933/recurrence-relation-for-the-number-of-ternary-strings-of-length-n-that-contain-e?rq=1 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488507/find-a-recurrence-relation-for-the-number-of-ternary-strings-of-length-n-that-co

Comment: @penyou: I think you mean $a_{n-1}$ instead of $n-1$ and $a_{n-2}$ instead of $n-2$ in the cases of strings starting with $2$ resp. $22$.

Answer (score 1):

> We can derive the recurrence relation for $a_n$ as follows:
>
> - **00|11**:  A string may start with either $00$ or $11$ leaving $\color{blue}{2\cdot 3^{n-2}}$ ways for the remaining substring of length $n-2$.
> - **22**: A string  may start with $22$ leaving $\color{blue}{a_{n-2}}$ ways for the remaining substring of length $n-2$.
>
> In all the other cases the string starts
>
> - **0(1|2)**: either with $0$ followed by $1$ or $2$
> - **1(0|2)**:  or with $1$ followed by $0$ or $2$
> - **2(0|1)**: or with $2$ followed by $0$ or $1$.
>
> In each of these *three* cases the first character is followed by *one of two* characters leaving $\color{blue}{2a_{n-1}}$ ways for the remaining substring of length $n-1$.

We conclude a recurrence relation for $a_n$ is
\begin{align*}
a_n&=2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+3\cdot 2^{n-2}\qquad\qquad n\geq 4\\
a_2&=2\\
a_3&=10
\end{align*}

The base cases $a_2=2$ and $a_3=10$ can be manually verified by
\begin{align*}
&n=2:\qquad 00,11\\
&n=3:\qquad 000,001,002,011,100,110,111,112,200,211
\end{align*}